# how to create dynamic app from google play

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

i want to download app from Google play from link. Thant means, http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackagename&MYCUSTOMID=xxxx

from the above url,i need to install the app which have the package name as id and a custom id from the url.That id should unique for that particular link.and the MYCUSTOMID value can be retrieve to that app.Is there any way....?

**AIM:I need to verify the app from which URL the app has been installed.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for identifying-app-installations, check Tim Bray'` [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html). Else,

if you are looking for licensing then this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) will help you.
From android documentation-

> Google Play offers a licensing service that lets you enforce licensing policies for applications that you publish on Google Play. With Google Play Licensing, your application can query Google Play at run time to obtain the licensing status for the current user, then allow or disallow further use as appropriate.